# Why does Lord Harkon do nothing when I accept his offer of becoming a vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I come in to Castle Volkihar and I accept Lord Harkon's offer of becoming a vampire and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

This is a (sadly) common bug.
Usually the only fix is to reload a previous save.
But what works (PC only as far as i know seeing you need access to console commands) is to go to the entrance door, activate console commands (press ` next to the 1 on your keyboard) click on the door in the console command menu and then type **unlock** go outside and then back in and the quest semi resets.